# Rails find all resources belonging to and shared with another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model which has_many :videos.

I want the list of videos to include videos shared with them, this is represented by a polymorphic Share model where the shareable type would be Video in this instance.

My question is how do I call user.videos and get back a list of videos that the user owns and also has shared with them?

Alternatively is there a way to define a :videos_including_shared method on the User model which would serve the same purpose?

**share.rb**

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base

  # The owner of the thing being shared
  belongs_to :shared_by, class_name: "User" # , ploymorphic: true

  # The user with whom the owner has shared the video with
  belongs_to :shared_with, class_name: "User" # , ploymorphic: true

  # The thing being shared
  belongs_to :shareable, polymorphic: true

  ...
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :videos, -> { order("created_at desc") }, dependent: :destroy

  # Resources that this user has shared
  has_many :shares, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "shared_by_id", inverse_of: :shared_by

  # Resources that this user have shared with them
  has_many :reverse_shares, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "shared_with_id", class_name: "Share", inverse_of: :shared_with

  # Videos which this user has shared
  has_many :shared_videos, through: :shares, source: :shareable, source_type: "Video"

  # Videos which have been shared with this user by other users
  has_many :videos_shared_with, through: :reverse_shares, source: :shareable, source_type: "Video"

  ...
```

**video.rb**

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :video

  belongs_to  :user
  has_many    :shares, as: :shareable, dependent: :destroy

  ...
```

---

**EDIT**

Seems like the answer to the alternative approach (using an instance method) looks like this (I thought...):

```
def videos_including_shared_with
  videos.merge(videos_shared_with)
end
```

This is close but it's returning a where clause that is using "AND" where it needs to be an "OR". So still no luck, it however I find a way to get this working I'd still like to see how this might be accomplished using scope

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to be hard using the 'videos' association as that will, as you mentioned in you edit, limit your scope to videos belonging to the user. You can do this in one query on `Video`, however:

```
Video.includes(:shares).where('videos.user_id = ? OR shares.shared_with_id =?', user_id, user_id)
```

I didn't rebuild your AR relation structure, but off the top of my head I would say this should work (as a caveat, I don't use polymorphic associations because I'm paranoid about referential integrity, but for a non-polymorphic I'm 95% sure this would work, so hopefully it's good for your case).

Comment: Yep, got it working yesterday using the same method you've outlined here. Still want to see if anyone can offer up anything else before I mark this as the answer.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. It only selects from the videos table and hence throws an error because it doesn't know what shares is in the where clause.